# Pawn Language : Parameters in the enum function

Tags: pawn

I'm learning about `Pawn` language . I'm having trouble with parameters in the `enum` function

```
enum E_MY_TAG (<<= 1)
{
    E_MY_TAG_NONE,
    E_MY_TAG_VAL_1 = 1,
    E_MY_TAG_VAL_2,
    E_MY_TAG_VAL_3,
    E_MY_TAG_VAL_4
}

new
    E_MY_TAG:gMyTagVar = E_MY_TAG_VAL_2 | E_MY_TAG_VAL_3;
```

I learned that the values in the `enum` will increment by default by `+=1`
And my lesson says the code :

```
new E_MY_TAG:gMyTagVar = E_MY_TAG_VAL_2 | E_MY_TAG_VAL_3;
```

*That will create a new variable and assign it the value 6 (4 | 2)*

I don't understand it , why the value of `E_MY_TAG_VAL_2` is `4` and `E_MY_TAG_VAL_3` is `2` and the parameter in the enum function why it is `<<=1` , i remember there is no such operator

Answer (score 1):

This enumerator contains bit flag values. First enum value is implicitly initialized with 0, second is explicitly initialized with 1, and the rest are initialized by applying `<<=1` (left bit shift operator that is essentially equivalent to multiplying by 2) to the previous value and will be 2, 4, 8. `gMyTagVar` is composed using `bitwise OR` operator. You may want to get familiar with [bitwise operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation).

Comment: Precisely. The Pawn Language Guide states that "(*increment*)" is "(*operator* *constant*)" where *operator* is only `+=`, `*=` or `<<=`.